# Hive SubQuery and Group BY

Tags: group-by, hive, in-subquery

I have two tables

table1:

```
id
1
2
3
```

table 2:

```
id date
1   x1
4   x2
1   x3
3   x4
3   x5
1   x6
3   x5
6   x6
6   x5
3   x6
```

**I want the count of each ids for table 2 that is present in table 1.**

Result

```
id  count
1   3
2   0
3   4
```

I am using this query, but its giving me error:

```
SELECT tab2.id, count(tab2.id)
 FROM <mytable2> tab2
 GROUP BY tab2.id
 WHERE tab2.id IN (select id from <mytable1>)
 ;
```

Error is:

> missing EOF at 'WHERE' near 'di_device_id'

Comment: you need to join to table 1 if you want to restrict to ids present in table 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible issues. Sub queries in the WHERE clause are only supported from Hive 0.13 and up. If you are using such a version, then your problem is just that you have WHERE and GROUP BY the wrong way round:

```
SELECT tab2.id, count(tab2.id)
 FROM <mytable2> tab2
 WHERE tab2.id IN (select id from <mytable1>)
 GROUP BY tab2.id
 ;
```

If you are using an older version of Hive then you need to use a JOIN:

```
SELECT tab2.id, count(tab2.id)
 FROM <mytable2> tab2 INNER JOIN <mytable1> tab1 ON (tab2.id = tab1.id)
 GROUP BY tab2.id
 ;
```

Comment: thanks. that was the issue, I was using 'where' after the group by.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues :-

1. `Where` comes before group by. In SQL syntax you use `having` to filter after grouping by!
2. Hive doesn't support all types of nested queries in Where clause. See here: [Hive Subqueries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)

However yours type of sub query will be ok. Try this:-

```
SELECT tab2.id, count(tab2.id)
 FROM <mytable2> tab2
 WHERE tab2.id IN (select id from <mytable1>)
 GROUP BY tab2.id;
```

It will do exactly same thing what you meant.

**Edit**: I Just checked @MattinBit's answer. I didn't intended to duplicate the answer. His answer is more complete!

Comment: thanks. that was the issue, I was using 'where' after the group by.. Thanks a lot.